# Request authorization error in Spotify API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, environment-variables, spotify

The weirdest thing is happening to my react app. I have moved the Client Id and Client Secret into the environment variables and am loading them into this file using dotenv to create an [authorization request](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/):

```
// Inject environment variables
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const clientID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;

// Request authorization
const authOptions = {
  url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
  headers: {
    "Authorization":
      "Basic " +
      new Buffer.from(clientID + ":" + clientSecret).toString("base64"),
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
  },
  json: true,
};

export default authOptions;
```

But I'm getting a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()` error:

```
{ error: "invalid_client", error_description: "Invalid client" }
```

The weird part is that if hard code the client id and secret, it works flawlessly.

I have even printed the environment variables in the console and am getting the correct values but the moment I use them in the authorization header it stops working.

**Is there any way to fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you doing is using an env variable in react which isn't available in the browser.

> *Just a side note*, maybe you shouldn't load secrets in the browser as that isn't a secure environment. Rather use the OAuth strategy for
> using your client id. [Here's a link](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/#:%7E:text=Which%20OAuth%20flow%20should%20I%20use%3F)

To load environment variables to your app. You'd need to prefix it with `REACT_APP_`. [Here's a link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Here's an example

.env

```
REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID=my-spotify-client-id
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once. I reset my `client_secret`, added the new value in the `.env` file, but forgot to terminate my app and run it again. After I rerun my app, it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I even deleted the app in the Spotify Dashboard and created another one but the problem still persists.

Comment: I mean to rerun the Nodejs app.

Comment: Yes I have been doing that as well but with no success